# Rate exceeded error when calling AWS CloudFront update

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I have to delete CloudFront distribution using AWS SDK for JavaScript so I'm trying to update it first, but when I sent the request I'm getting `Rate exceeded` internal server error. I tried many different values inside my config but it always returns this rate error. I'm not sure if it's problem with configuration or maybe I did something else wrong. I have also created function that creates new distribution and it works fine.

My current config object looks like this:

```
  const originId = `S3-${buckets.build.name}`;
  const originDomain = `${buckets.build.name}.s3.amazonaws.com`;

  const updateParams: CloudFront.UpdateDistributionRequest = {
    Id: distribution.id,
    IfMatch: distribution.eTag,
    DistributionConfig: {
      DefaultRootObject: 'index.html',
      CallerReference: caller,
      Comment: 'Zilo catalog',
      DefaultCacheBehavior: {
        AllowedMethods: {
          Items: ['HEAD', 'GET'],
          Quantity: 2,
          CachedMethods: {
            Items: ['HEAD', 'GET'],
            Quantity: 2,
          },
        },
        TargetOriginId: originId,
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: 'allow-all',
        MinTTL: 3600,
        SmoothStreaming: false,
        Compress: false,
        DefaultTTL: 5000,
        FieldLevelEncryptionId: '',
        MaxTTL: 10000,
        LambdaFunctionAssociations: {
          Quantity: 0,
          Items: [],
        },
        ForwardedValues: {
          QueryString: true,
          Cookies: {
            Forward: 'all',
          },
          Headers: {
            Quantity: 0,
            Items: [],
          },
          QueryStringCacheKeys: {
            Quantity: 0,
            Items: [],
          },
        },
      },
      Enabled: false,
      Origins: {
        Items: [
          {
            DomainName: originDomain,
            Id: originId,
            CustomOriginConfig: {
              HTTPPort: 80,
              HTTPSPort: 443,
              OriginProtocolPolicy: 'match-viewer',
              OriginSslProtocols: { Items: ['SSLv3'], Quantity: 1 },
              OriginReadTimeout: 10000,
              OriginKeepaliveTimeout: 10000,
            },
            OriginPath: '',
            CustomHeaders: { Quantity: 0 },
          },
        ],
        Quantity: 1,
      },
      Aliases: {
        Quantity: 0,
      },
      Logging: {
        Enabled: false,
        IncludeCookies: false,
        Bucket: '',
        Prefix: '',
      },
      WebACLId: '',
      HttpVersion: 'http2',
      Restrictions: {
        GeoRestriction: {
          RestrictionType: 'none',
          Quantity: 0,
        },
      },
      ViewerCertificate: {
        MinimumProtocolVersion: 'SSLv3',
      },
      CustomErrorResponses: {
        Items: [],
        Quantity: 0,
      },
      PriceClass: 'PriceClass_100',
      CacheBehaviors: { Quantity: 0, Items: [] },
    },
  };
```

Any ideas what could gone wrong here?

Comment: The error usually means that you are calling AWS API to fast. How are you executing this code?

Comment: I created cloudfront service:

class _CloudFrontService {
   disableDistribution({ buckets, distribution }: CatalogConfig) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
       const updateParams: CloudFront.UpdateDistributionRequest = {
         ...
      };

       this.cloudFront.updateDistribution(updateParams, (err, data) =>
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(data),
      );
    });
  }
}


and I'm calling it like this:
await CloudFrontService.disableDistribution(catalogConfig);

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same issue while attempting to disable CloudFront distribution before deleting it. Ended up finding this working solution in Java:

```
GetDistributionConfigResponse distributionConfigResponse =
            cloudFrontClient.getDistributionConfig(GetDistributionConfigRequest.builder().id(distributionId).build());
   
distributionETag = distributionConfigResponse.eTag();
DistributionConfig originalConfig = distributionConfigResponse.distributionConfig();
        
UpdateDistributionResponse updateDistributionResponse =
            cloudFrontClient.updateDistribution(r -> r.id(distributionId)
                                                      .ifMatch(distributionETag)
                                                      .distributionConfig(originalConfig.toBuilder()
                                                                                        .enabled(false)
                                                                                        .build()));
```